# VB.NET sqlatasource retrieve id with scope_identity()

Tags: sqldatasource

I'm having some sqldatasource issues.  I want to insert 3 values into a DB table, then get the auto-incremented ID.  I've read all about scope_identity but I'm having trouble structuring everything correctly.  We paid developers to build our website but I've taken over the programming so I'm working with existing code and trying to modify.

Here's what I have in the subroutine when a user clicks:

```
dim firstlike As Integer = 1
likeslbl.Text = firstlike
sqlvoted.InsertParameters.Clear()
sqlvoted.InsertCommand = "INSERT INTO urls (url,likes,mlsid) SELECT ?url,?likes,?mlsid; SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS @newID"
sqlvoted.InsertParameters.Add("url", System.Data.DbType.String, url)
sqlvoted.InsertParameters.Add("likes", System.Data.DbType.String, firstlike.ToString)
sqlvoted.InsertParameters.Add("mlsid", System.Data.DbType.String, newmlsid)
sqlvoted.Insert()
```

And here is my sqldatasource:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource id="sqlvoted" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ConnectionStrings:Mym6pConnection %>"
ProviderName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient">
<SelectParameters>
<asp:Parameter Direction="Output" Name="newID" Type="Int32" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Everything works correctly if I remove the "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS @newID" portion of the insertCommand.  I'm just not really sure how to integrate that with the rest of it.  I'm guessing it has something to do with double "select" statements. I don't understand how the "SELECT ?url,?likes,?mlsid" statement works, though.  Everywhere else that I've looked that part of the command has been "VALUES @url,@likes,@mlsid" but that doesn't work. Any assistance here would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
jared

Comment: Can I add the output parameter as part of an sqlvoted.InsertParameters.Add statement up above with the rest of the parameters?  If so, what should my command look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dim str as string = "INSERT INTO urls (url,likes,mlsid) VALUES ('" & url & "','" & firstlike.ToString & "','" & newmlsid & "');SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS newID"

And assign str to InsertCommand.
 sqlvoted.InsertCommand = str
 sqlvoted.Insert()

Comment: Awesome, looks like it likes that one.  THANK YOU!!  Now I need to grab that newID value that was returned.  I think I know how... if not I will be back.  Thanks again.

Comment: @JaredVenema Can you please mark it as answer if it has solved your issue. Cheers :)